# Замена символов в URL на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В `Url manager` написал простое правило для URL товаров с категориями

```
'rules' => [
....
     '<category>/<type>/<id>' => 'product/view',
....
],
```

URL формируется, в контроллере обрататываю. Но проблема в том, что есть категории с пробелами, и есть категории на кириллице, есть в разном регистре.

Кто знает, какие и как прописать правила для замены такого URL - `/Junior+Girl/` , на `/junior-girl/`?

Comment: так в правила можно писать регулярные выражения.... напиши регулярку, которая будет case insensitive и всё

Comment: Каким образом у вас формируется URL? Можете показать этот кусок кода?

Comment: Думаю правильней будет при добавлении формировать правильный урл и хранить в базе, потом по них уже выводить. Вопрос не актуален

Comment: я правильно понял, что у вас слаги для сущностей с пробелами и на русском?! ?!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего в таком случае будет подключить к вашей модели поведение Sluggable, которое будет добавлять специальную сгенерированную по указанному полю строку и сохранять ее в базе. Так вы сможете более жестко контролировать поиск конкретной модели